Multiplying a 2D array with a 3D array of vectors in Numpy
I have a dxd matrix that I would like to multiply with a dx1xn matrix. The idea is to get back another dx1xn matrix, so I would essentially like to multiply each dxd matrix with each dx1 matrix n times along that third axis. I have no idea how to go about this though. I have tried np.apply_along_axis and np.apply_over_axes, but the first only selects one axis rather than the dx1 matrices, and the second doesn't do what I want either.
k = 2
s = 36
d = k + s - 1
n = 1119

T = np.zeros(shape=(d, d)
alpha_filt = np.zeros(shape=(d, 1, n))

# Doesn't work obviously
np.matmul(T, alpha_filt)


I think you want to do batched matrix multiplication, which you can do with np.matmul, but the batch dimension(s) have to be leading. For instance, if alpha_filt was shape (n, d, 1), your current code would work fine.
You can use transpose to make that happen:
out = np.matmul(T, alpha_filt.transpose(2, 0, 1)).transpose(1, 2, 0)

but it might be easier to refactor your code so that you work with (n, d, 1) arrays rather than (d, 1, n).
In your case, it might be even easier to remove the axis with size 1 entirely:
out = np.matmul(T, alpha_filt.squeeze())[:, None]


Looks like a job for np.einsum
out = np.einusm('ij, jkl -> ikl', T, alpha_filt)

